# Is there a good way to share the seed of random between modules (in python)?

Tags: python, random, seed, global

I have a project with different main files (for different simulations).
When I run one of the mainfiles, it should set a seed to random (and numpy.random), and all the modules in the project should use that seed.

I don't find a good way to do this. I have a file globals.py with this:

```
import random

myRandom=None


def initSeed(seed):
    global myRandom
    myRandom =random.Random(seed)
```

then from a main I do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    seed=10
    globals.initSeed(seed)
...
```

Then in the modules that main calls, I do:

```
from globals import myRandom
```

But myRandom has the value None in the module (even though I modified it in main!). Why, and how to fix it? Is there a nicer way?

Comment: If you want to do it by using `global`, the variable should be declared `global` in all functions that use it. You could use classes and subclasses but you might as well write the value to a file. I think you'd access the variable `myRandom` via `globals.myRandom` in your current setup. Btw. `globals` is already defined in Python so change the filename to something else (not `glob` - also taken)

Comment: `it should set a seed to random and all the modules in the project should use that seed.` Sound like you are looking for singletons ?

Comment: I just wonder what is your use-case scenario

Comment: My use-case is research: I have models, and I have to run them in different ways (e.g. with different parameters, plotting different stuff, etc.). I create modules for the models and simulation files that are like execution profiles, to put it somehow.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a file to avoid `global` and to separate data and logic a bit.

**seed_handler.py**

```
# file that stores the shared seed value 
seed_val_file = "seed_val.txt"

def save_seed(val, filename=seed_val_file):
    """ saves val. Called once in simulation1.py """
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(str(val))

def load_seed(filename=seed_val_file):
    """ loads val. Called by all scripts that need the shared seed value """
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        # change datatype accordingly (numpy.random.random() returns a float)
        return int(f.read())
```

**simulation1.py**

```
import random
import seed_handler

def sim1():
    """ creates a new seed and prints a deterministic "random" number """
    new_seed = int("DEADBEEF",16) # Replace with numpy.random.random() or whatever
    print "New seed:", new_seed
    # do the actual seeding of the pseudo-random number generator
    random.seed(new_seed)
    # the result
    print "Random:  ", random.random()
    # save the seed value so other scripts can use it
    seed_handler.save_seed(new_seed)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sim1()
```

**simulation2.py**

```
import random
import seed_handler

def sim2():
    """ loads the old seed and prints a deterministic "random" number """
    old_seed = seed_handler.load_seed()
    print "Old seed:", old_seed
    # do the actual seeding of the pseudo-random number generator
    random.seed(old_seed)
    # the result
    print "Random:  ", random.random()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sim2()
```

Output:

```
user@box:~/$ python simulation1.py 
New seed: 3735928559
Random:   0.0191336454935

user@box:~/$ python simulation2.py 
Old seed: 3735928559
Random:   0.0191336454935
```

ADDENDUM

I just read in the comments that this is for research. At the moment, executing simulation1.py overwrites the stored seed value; this might not be desirable. One could add one of these features:

1. save as json and load to dictionary; that way nothing
   would get overwritten and every seed value could have notes, a timestamp and a
   user-generated label associated with it.
2. simply prompt the user for a yes/no to overwriting the
   existing value.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a particularly good idea given that the OP mentioned they are doing this for research purposes. They should probably be storing the seed in a more permanent way than a global variable in case they need to replicate a run or extend their model.

Comment: @Paul       
 
Thanks, I think you're right. Actually, the whole idea of overwriting values might be unwise in that context. The thought of having to reverse engineer the random module to find out which seed value created a given output is certainly unappealing!

Answer (score 1):

1. As mentioned by @jDo in comment, renamed `globals.py` into `randGlobal.py`.
2. Added a module `testResult.py` for testing.

---

## randGlobal.py

```
import random

def initSeed(seed):
    # declare
    global myRandom
    myRandom = random.Random(seed)
```

## testResult.py

```
import randGlobal

def randOutput():
    return randGlobal.myRandom.random()
```

## main.py

```
import randGlobal

# Add a module for testing
import testResult


def test():
    result = testResult.randOutput()
    print result


# main
if __name__ == "__main__":

    seed=10
    randGlobal.initSeed(seed)
    # after init, hava a test
    test()
```